# Access to QCheckBox from QWidgetAction

Tags: c++, qt

Please consider the bellow codes:

```
QMenu* menu_ = new QMenu(this);
QWidgetAction *checkableAction = new QWidgetAction(menu_);

QCheckBox* checkBox1 = new QCheckBox("Sample1", menu_);
QCheckBox* checkBox2 = new QCheckBox("Sample2", menu_);

checkableAction->setDefaultWidget(checkBox1);
checkableAction->setDefaultWidget(checkBox2);

connect(checkableAction, &QWidgetAction::toggled, this, &MenuPushButton::onRec_triggered);
```

How can I access to QCheckBox features from QWidgetAction in `onRec_triggered` slot. I try the bellow codes but it does not works for me.

```
void MenuPushButton::onRec_triggered()
{
    for(QAction* action : menu_->actions())
        if(dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(action)->isChecked())
            qDebug()<<dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(action)->text();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on code snippets provided by question. However i am not sure if the intention was to use "checkable" feature of base class `QAction`.

If you want to use the checkbox you set as `QWidgetAction` default widget to trigger your slot then you have to use `connect(checkBox2, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, &MenuPushButton::onRec_triggered);`. You can remove `checkBox1` as it gets overridden by `checkBox2` as default widget. In your slot you have to use a two step `dynamic_cast`. First `dynamic_cast` to check if `action` is of type `QWidgetAction *` and if that matches call `defaultWidget()` and try to `dynamic_cast` result to `QCheckBox *`. If that matches too then call `text()` method. Always check result of `dynamic_cast` before you call any method to avoid accessing a `nullptr`.

```
void MenuPushButton::onRec_triggered()
{
    for(QAction* action : menu_->actions()) {
        QWidgetAction *wa = dynamic_cast<QWidgetAction*>(action);
        if (wa) {
            QCheckBox *cb = dynamic_cast<QCheckBox*>(wa->defaultWidget());
            if (cb) {
                qDebug() << cb->text();
            }
        }
    }
}
```